# How to optionally change the CSRF name in security class

Tags: codeigniter, csrf

I have post data coming from an external cURL POST.  I do not have the ability to add any custom defined fields to the post back but I can stuff the CSFR token into another empty input for post back to my app.  Is it feasible to do this and then modify the security class to look for the unique input name in _POST data when the expected csfr_token isn't found?

If this solution makes sense then any suggestions on how to implement will be more than appreicated.

Answer (score 2):

That can be done using the configuration file: `application/config/config.php`. Just do a search for `csrf` and you will find it.

If you need "one time use" for a token name, you can use `$this->config->set_item('item','value')` method to set the `csrf_token_name` to what you need for that particular request.

It is not recommended to modify core classes, as that will prevent a later easy CI upgrade, should you want one.

Answer (score -2):

You can set the name of the CFRF token in **/system/core/Security.php**.

It is a protected attribute about line 32.

```
protected $_csrf_token_name = 'ci_csrf_token';
```

To keep the purists happy, you could (or should) write your own extended Security class instead of editing a core file

Comment: -1. You don't have to override the security class to change the CSRF token. It's in `application/config/config.php` and the variable is `$config['csrf_token_name']`. No need to mess with a core file, extend the class, or anything.